# initialize two input fields as datepicker with different html class

Tags: javascript, datepicker, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the bootstrap datepicker gem https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails

In this gem, i am able to use simple_form to build a form that has two input fields called start_date and end_date like this

```
 <% simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :start_date, :as => :date_time_picker, wrapper_html: {class: 'start-date'} %>
   <%= f.input :end_date, :as => :date_time_picker, wrapper_html: {class: 'end-date'} %>
 <% end %>
```

I followed their example and built custom date time input as follows

```
class DateTimePickerInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  def input(wrapper_options)
    template.content_tag(:div, class: 'input-group date date-picker') do
      template.concat @builder.text_field(attribute_name, merge_wrapper_options(input_html_options, wrapper_options))
      template.concat span_remove
      template.concat span_table
    end
  end

  def input_html_options
    super.merge({class: 'form-control', readonly: true})
  end

  def span_remove
    template.content_tag(:span, class: 'input-group-addon') do
      template.concat icon_remove
    end
  end

  def span_table
    template.content_tag(:span, class: 'input-group-addon') do
      template.concat icon_table
    end
  end

  def icon_remove
    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>".html_safe
  end

  def icon_table
    "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-th'></i>".html_safe
  end

end
```

and i initialized via javascript the datetimepicker input fields as follows

```
$('.date-picker').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: today
})
```

My problem now is that i want to set that the selected date of `start_date` is the min date for `end_date` but i cannot use the `changeDate` event since both of my input fields are using the same class `date-picker`. How can i define these two input fields with like classes that i can then use to initialize the datepicker for both in javascript and perform the expected logic for `end_date`

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `How can i define these two input fields with like classes` don't you already gave each one its own class? As far as I can tell, this is a purely client-side problem; what does the final HTML look like? Taking your question title at face value, what you do is `$('.start-date, .end-date').datepicker({ ... });` I don't see why you can't use a `changeDate` handler. Nobody is forcing you to apply it to both datepickers.

Comment: Here's the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ybpk6oLt/

Comment: because simple_form ends up not wrapping the classes to the input, they end up getting wrapped to the div instead which is not what i want.